# Magento Observer problem

Tags: xml, event-observer

I followed every step from this website : http://alanstorm.com/magento_config and I'm stuck with the observer.

I think smth is wrong with my **Observer.php**. I get this error :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:157:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /mnt/futurehome/netlogiq/public_html/attin/magento/app/code/local/Attila/Configviewer/Model/Observer.php, line 1";i:1;s:1142:"#0 /mnt/futurehome/netlogiq/public_html/attin/magento/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true).....
```

I post this image : [image]

Also I comment the code from observer I did not get this error. Can someone help me with this ?

**=> config.xml :**

```
<config>
    <modules>...</modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_front_init_routers>
                <observers>
                    <attila_configviewer_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>                          
                        <class>Attila_Configviewer_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkForConfigRequest</method>
                    </attila_configviewer_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_front_init_routers>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**=> Observer.php :**

```
 <?php
    class Attila_Configviewer_Model_Observer {
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'showConfig';
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT = 'showConfigFormat';     

        private $request;

        public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {          
            $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
            if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'){
                $this->setHeader();
                $this->outputConfig();
            }
        }

        private function setHeader() {
            $format = isset($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT}) ? 
            $this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT} : 'xml';                                
            switch($format){
                case 'text':
                    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
                    break;
                default:
                    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
            }           
        }

        private function outputConfig() {            
            die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());      
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: please share some of your code which you tried.if their is problem in code we can help you.

Comment: please check the post again :)

Comment: make sure that in the file `Attila/Configviewer/Model/Observer.php` you don't have any space or other character before the php opening tag (`<?php`) or after the closing tag `?>`. Actually you can remove the closing tag completely if you have one.

Comment: @Marius thx man , that was the problem :D can I add you on skype ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this question will have an answer.

Based on the comments the problem was cause by a character (probably space) at the beginning of the observer file, before the php opening tag (`<?php`) and it was considered output.